# Permissions of Shared Folder on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, share

I Have a VM of Windows Server 2003 running on Windows 7. On Windows 2003 there is a folder I have shared, how would I set up permissions to allow access of this folder in Windows 7? I am not sure how to add the user from my Windows 7 account to Windows 2003.

I am not running an Active Directory, both systems are on WorkGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't, in a workgroup configuration. That's what AD and its groups are for. Your login will strictly be destination\user (where the destination is the actual machine where the share is - in your case, your host).

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get this to work seamlessly is to create a user on Server 2003 with the same account name as the one on the Windows 7 box, and then make sure the passwords are the same on both machines. Win7 will attempt to connect to Windows 2003 with the credentials of the logged in user. If those credentials happen to match one that it already has, it'll look like there was no login (even though there was).

Comment: I have this already done and it does not work.